# PHP file permission on Linux puzzle

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I copy a test.php from a folder and here is it's permission:

> -rw-r--r--.  1 root root       20 Jan 12 19:01 test.php

I try to run this script and it says:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Then i delete this file and create a new one by vim test.php,and here is it's permission:

> -rw-r--r--.  1 root root       20 Jan 12 19:01 test.php

again, i run this file and it works!

anyone knows why?

Comment: How are you trying to run it? And with which user? If it is from a server, you should increase permissions to 755

Comment: I don't think so, i am sure the way which i run it is right. the file create by vim can be execute normally

Comment: Please share how you are running it.

Comment: A php file should need only be readable not executable, since it is the php interpreter that executes by reading the source code from a `.php` file.  So your permissions on the actual file are fine.  It seems to me that you are trying to include the `test.php` file using a `require` statement.  If so the directory that `test.php` is in must be executable for the user that runs php otherwise it will not be able to access files in that directory.

Comment: @tholu I run this file by input http://localhost/test.php